# Surface is cut by a plane, producing a line. Find the slope of the line.

Tags: calculus

> The surface $z=y^2 - x^2$ is cut by the plane $y=3x$, producing a curve in the plane. Find the slope of this curve at the point $(1,3,8)$.

I am not sure how to approach this. I think I should use directional derivative but not sure how. I calculated the gradient at $(1,3,8)$ already:

$$\nabla z=\langle-2x,2y\rangle=\langle -2,6\rangle$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Did you make a typo while typing the question? $(1,3,-8)$ is not on the curve; perhaps you meant $(1,3,8)$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we should find a parametrisation of the curve of intersection. Set $x=t$, then the equations of the line and surface give
$$y=3t\qquad z=(3t)^2-t^2=8t^2$$
So a parametric representation of the curve is
$${\bf r}(t)=\langle t,3t,8t^2\rangle,\ t\in\Bbb R$$
and we see that the point $(1,3,8)$ corresponds to $t=1$. Taking derivatives of each component yields the gradient:
$${\bf r}'(t)=\langle1,3,16t\rangle$$
and substituting $t=1$ gives ${\bf r}'(1)=\langle1,3,16\rangle$. The slope of the curve in the plane at $(1,3,8)$ is therefore
$$s=\frac{z'}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}=\frac{16}{\sqrt{3^2+1^2}}=\frac{16}{\sqrt{10}}=8\sqrt{\frac25}$$